# "One of the most" VS "Some of the most"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, subject-verb-agreement, modifiers

My painstaking grammarphobia is making me pull my hair out trying to figure wrap my head around the usage of "one of the most" and "some of the most".

Take for example:

- A cheetah is ONE of the fastest animals on the planet. **(Singular Subject)**
- Cheetahs are SOME of the fastest animals on the planet. **(Plural Subject)**

Then this should technically be wrong or less accurate, right?

- Cheetahs are ONE of the fastest animals on the planet. **(Plural Subject)**
  (I feel like in this case, "one of the most" shouldn't be used and keep the sentence "Cheetahs are the fastest animals on the planet.")

The reason I ask is because I have run into this by somebody, who is supposed to be a skilled writer but could be wrong:

- Cigarettes are ONE of the leading causes of lung cancer.
- Cigarettes are SOME of the leading causes of lung cancer.

Grammatically, my logic is telling me that SOME should be used, but then there is another voice in my head saying ONE sounds better even though it’s not technically just one cigarette.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question where descriptive and prescriptive grammarians are likely to disagree.

Sentences like

> Cigarettes are one of the leading causes of cancer.

abound, even among the fully literate. So a descriptive grammarian will say the sentence above is grammatical. Of course, when interpreted literally, it makes no sense. What is meant that is grammatical, internally consistent with respect to number, and sensible is

> Smoking cigarettes is one of the leading causes of cancer.

A prescriptive grammarian might say the second sentence is preferable. A stylist would say the second sentence is preferable because it is more accurate: unsmoked cigarettes are not one of the leading causes of cancer. But ellipsis is part of English grammar: "smoking" will be understood. Even the most dogmatic of prescriptive grammarians would not approve

> Cigarettes is one of the leading causes of cancer

or

> Cigarettes are some of the leading causes of cancer.

The first captures meaning correctly, but violates the grammatical rule demanding a plural verb after a plural subject. The second is grammatical but does not reflect intended meaning.

Grammar is the servant of meaning, and grammar trumps logic. The issue is that ellipsis creates an unnecessary conflict. Usage says "cigarettes are one of" is grammatical despite the mathematical inconsistency between plural subject and "one." The reason I dislike it is that it is excessively broad: what is meant is "smoking" or "smoking cigarettes" rather than the mere existence of cigarettes.

Ellipsis is also the problem in your cheetah example. What is meant is not cheetahs individually, but cheetahs as a species. What is meant is

> The species of cheetahs is one of the fastest on earth.

Ellipsis permits

> Cheetahs are one of the fastest species on earth.

Grammar is not always mathematically consistent.

Comment: This is a great answer, though I suspect that some users of this site actually **are** dogmatic enough to endorse a sentence like "Cigarettes are some of the leading causes of cancer."

Comment: Thank you such in-depth explanation. This is why I always find grammar to be the most turmoil thing when I’m writing, for instance, when I come across some questionable grammar that disrupts what I think I know or have been taught in school, my mind shuts off and can’t even proceed until this sort of itch is scratch per say.

Comment: I seriously don’t remember grammar being this subjective and varied. Back in school, I found it a lot simpler where teachers gave the rules being black-and-white to stick by them...no matter what...to keep things simple.

And probably a good thing too, because thinking about all these subjective possibilities of nuances just create headaches to keep track of and unable to learn the grammar rules, like basically saying “for ellipsis, 1 + 1 = Does not equal 2,” creates more confusion.

Comment: It is not so much a matter of subjectivity. It is a matter of two different schools of thought regarding grammar. Descriptive grammarians rely on what people actually say. Prescriptive grammarians specify what people should do. It often leads to different answers. Personally, I usually find that apparent grammatical issues reflect failure to specify my intended meaning carefully, and addressing the meaning eliminates any grammatical issue  Grammar serves meaning, not formal logic.

Comment: What school of thought would you consider that school teaches (like AP English) falls under? Old habits die hard.

Comment: It tends toward the prescriptive. You should understand that neither approach is absolutist. Prescriptivists understand that the rules they prescribe must be those actually followed by the best writers over time and so do agree that usage counts. And descriptivists understand that the relevant usage is what a material percentage of the population says and so do agree that not just anything ever heard is grammatical.

Comment: I see. So in other words, these examples below are all grammatically correct depending what we want to convey?

Comment: 1. Cheetahs are the fastest animals on the planet. (Individually every cheetah living on the planet now)

2. Cheetahs are some of the fastest animals on the planet. (Multiple cheetahs, not all cheetahs on the planet though)

3. Cheetahs are one of the fastest animals on the planet. (Group of cheetahs or collective nouns among other fast animals that are not cheetahs. I still find this one to be the least correct, if not wrong)

4. (A) Cheetah is one of the fastest animals on the planet. (One cheetah to represent the cheetah group/species, like a politician representing the people)

Comment: Your first example is grammatical but ambiguous. The sentence is grammatically consistent with the absurd meaning that no other type of animal on earth is faster than any cheetah. How about cheetahs that are two days old or are lame? The sentence is also consistent with the sensible assertion that “Healthy, adult cheetahs are almost always faster than healthy, adult members of almost all other species.” And that is how most people will interpret your first sentence because, unlike computers, they interpret through common sense and grammar. See next comment

Comment: You are trying to make grammar the arbiter of meaning and insisting that grammar preclude technically illogical statements. You can say illogical things grammatically. To decipher meaning, grammar is just one tool used by human beings.